# Median age by state/city in Germany?

Tags: data-request, demographics, germany, population

I would like to get any data that show median age by city/state in Germany (in English). For example, in Berlin it is 42.4, in Munich it is 43.7, etc...

It would also be better if I can get just the whole population demographics, such as in Berlin the number of males whose age is 20-24 is XXX, and male 25-29 is YYY, etc... for all states/cities. I would like to know which state is young and which is old, for your information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the puzzle pieces to answer your question are available at https://ergebnisse.zensus2011.de/?locale=en#StaticContent:00,BEV_11_1,m,table

It gives you population, by age and gender, for all of Deutschland as well as by Land, Administrative region, and District. Data is as of 2011.

The site allows an export as XLS and CSV too

Comment: Thanks. Why has this not been updated since then? Maybe it is updated per 5 years, right?

Comment: From what I read it was actually done by the EU census and yes every 5 years